# Get list values of list from dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the following code snippet to add string values to a List and then add the list as the key in a dictionary. Now I want to print both the key and the value from the Dictionary but I'm unable to do so.  Any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated.

```
Dictionary<List<string>, int> dic = new Dictionary<List<string>, int>();

List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
string[] str = new string[5];
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Type Number:");
    string test = Console.ReadLine();
    mylist.Add(test);
    counter++;
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", mylist));
dic.Add(mylist, counter);
```

Comment: Side note: are you sure `List<string>` should be the key of dictionary, not its value?

Comment: List<string> is a key

Comment: Well, it's up to you. But it looks very curious.... At least you have to create custom comparator in the case of `List<string>` to be the key. Otherwise it is possible to add duplicates into your dictionary.

Comment: Poor design. As @AndyKorneyev pointed out, `List<string>` should not be the key to a dictionary. How would you even begin to look up an item? I can't think of one possible reason to do that.

Comment: It's not necessarily poor design - it depends on how he plans to use the Dictionary.  Using objects as keys to a Dictionary is no big deal...   In this case, the Dictionary value simply represents the order that the List was added to the Dictionary.

Comment: @MichaelBray - I agree about using objects as keys but a `List<T>` has no override for `GetHashCode` so uses the default inherited from `object`.  So its fine if you just want to iterate over the dictionary but you can't reliably use it as a lookup because a new `List<string>` instance with the same string values will produce a different HashCode so different key. So why not just reverse the key/value pair as the key is useless in this case?

Comment: @Igor yes - all valid points, and based on comments and responses from OP I've now seen on some of the answers, you are probably right.  I simply try not to make assumptions about how the OP intends to use the code in question.  In this case, I might turn your question around and ask "what use is storing the int as a key" - in other words, why not just use an array which would achieve the same purpose?  Two possible conclusions: either OP is a beginner programmer that's just learning, or there was intention behind his question.  Probably A, but not always good to assume that.  :)

Comment: @MichaelBray - based on the mistakes I see in his code sample and also his responses I am also leaning towards beginner programmer as well. Also I agree, the `Dictionary` has no purpose in his sample. His real question is "how can print the values of a `List<string>` to the console" or "how to iterate over a key/value pair collection" (or something like that), the rest of the code is unnecessary and detracts from the question.

Comment: @Igor I interpreted is as he actually wants "12345" `string` (not really `List<string>`) as key, but want to display in his console as "1,2,3,4,5", and having value of the length of the key (`counter` = `5`)

Comment: @Ian - could very well be. He did not give much to go on as far as expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach(var v in dic)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("," v.Key) + " " + v.Value.ToString());
```

Although, it does seem like you have your `key` and `value` backwards...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have `string` as you `key` (as you indicate by joining the `List<string>`, then consider making a `Dictionary<string,int>` instead of `Dictionary<List<string>,int>`:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>(); //note this dict type

List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
string[] str = new string[5];
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Type Number:");
    string test = Console.ReadLine();
    mylist.Add(test);
    counter++;
}

string key = string.Join("", mylist); //note this key combination
//you will have key-value pair such as "12345"-5

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", mylist)); //note, you will print as "1,2,3,4,5"
dic.Add(key, counter);
```

And print it out like what has been shown:

```
foreach(var v in dic)
    Console.WriteLine(v.Key.ToString() + " " + v.Value.ToString());
```

**Original:**

using `foreach` on each `Dictionary` element will do the job:

```
foreach(var v in dic)
    Console.WriteLine(v.Key.ToString() + " " + v.Value.ToString());
```

The `foreach` will allow you to iterate over every element in your `Dictionary`.

Additionally, you may consider to reverse your `Dictionary` key and value:

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dic = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

For it is quite uncommon to call `int` from `List<string>`. The `Key` part of the `Dictionary` is normally the simpler one. Also, by having a `List<string>` as `Key`, you have to have that exact `List<string>` to call the `Value`, but having `int` as you `Key` will allow you to get `List<string>` from `int` pretty easily.

And if you plan to `join` the `List<string>` you should use `<string,int>` or `<int,string>` rather than `<List<string>,int>` or `<int,List<string>>`

Comment: @misha130 not working, as in? Seems like the `Dictionary` is reversed

Comment: Actually OP didn't mention what was happening and what he was expecting. I just thought his string.join wasn't printing. Forget it

Comment: It is printing the list values as  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: @MohsinTester so you actually want your `List<string>` to be joined as `Key` are you?